# Postgresql find total disk space used by a database

Tags: database, postgresql, diskspace

I have more than 50 databases hosted in my postgresql server. I need to move some of them on another host, to free-up some disk space,but how can I measure the disk-space used by each database on my volume?

Is there any function exists to get the information that I want?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
SELECT pg_database_size('geekdb')
```

or

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('geekdb'))
```

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/05/15-advanced-postgresql-commands-with-examples/

Comment: To clarify, this actually shows the size of the DB, not how much space is left in the DB, which was the original question.

Answer (score 56):

You could use postgresql Meta-Commands:

- `\l` would list databases
- `\l+` extends list with Size, Tablespace, Description.

Use `\?` to get full list of meta-commands. Also see:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 10):

Execute the following query to show the size of each of the databases in the server.

```
SELECT datname as db_name, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) as db_usage FROM pg_database;
```

note: This is based on the accepted answer but the saves time of not having to run one query per database.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but I created a way to see the results of linux command `df -h` (Filesystem, Size, Used, Avail, Use%, Mounted on) via a sql query, thus your free disk space and total available disk space for a given file system. Not exactly what the question is about, but helpful for some of use/me. I wish that answer was here hours ago, so I am putting it here (linux only):

create a cron job like this:

```
@hourly df -h | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}' > /pathhere/diskspaceinfo.csv`
```

create a foreign table to query:

```
create extension file_fdw;

create server logserver FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE diskspaceinfo 
(file_sys text, size text, used text, avail text, used_pct text, mount text) 
SERVER fileserver 
OPTIONS (filename '/pathhere/diskspaceinfo.csv', format 'csv');
```

Then query your table like this:

```
select * from diskspaceinfo
```

If you just want something specific, of course just filter the table for what you want. It has limitations, but is very useful for me.

If you have `plperlu`, you could use this function:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Free_disk_space

A useful link:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage

Comment: Another +1 for mountain climbing from a montaineer!

Answer (score 2):

Love mountainclimber's answer.  I tweaked the cron to return bytes and remove the header row as follows.

```
* * * * * df -B1 | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}' > /var/www/diskspaceinfo.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

With an RDS Postgresql database you can use the FreeLocalStorage Cloudwatch metric subtracted from the value provided by the query @Robert Harvey provided to obtain the storage utilized.