# Sql memory issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a new postgres server and when I trying to execute this sql command:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_3;
 CREATE TABLE table_3 AS
    SELECT 
       t1.id,
       t1.fild_2,
       t1.fild_3,
       t1.fild_4,
       t1.fild_5,
       t2.fild_6,
       t2.fild_7,
       t2.fild_8
  FROM table1 t1
       RIGHT JOIN  table2 t2 
       ON t1.id = t2.id
```

table1 and table2 contains around 300 000 records
I got an error like this:

```
ERROR:  could not extend file "base/367684/370837.16": wrote only 4096 of 8192 bytes at block 2182494
HINT:  Check free disk space.
SQL state: 53100
```

Any ideas ?

Regards,
Arrmlet

Comment: perhaps you should check the free disk space? `HINT:  Check free disk space.` ??

Comment: That's not a "memory" issue, it's a disk space issue. The hard disk where your Postgres database is stored is full.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so I need to clean up disk space? Or what?

Comment: Problem with disk space
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346371/postgresql-find-total-disk-space-used-by-a-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `join` conditions are probably not correct.  You can calculate how many rows there are by using:

```
select sum(t2.cnt * coalesce(t1.cnt, 1))
from (select t2.id, count(*) as cnt
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.id
     ) t2 left join
     (select t1.id, count(*) as cnt
      from table1 t1
      group by t1
     ) t1
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

My guess is that the number of rows is way larger than you expect.  If that is the case, then running out of free space is merely a symptom of a badly formed query.

However, if this version of the query runs out of space, then the issue really is the free space.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my sql produce over 400 millions records of data

Comment: @Arrmlet . . . Sounds like your join if off if you are starting with only a few hundred thousand rows in each table.